# How to get Data from three tables in one query where table 2 contains foreign keys from table 1 and 3

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I want to get all the suppliers for one product with product details for which I am using following tables.

I have one Table `products` with columns

```
id(pk) 
name 
type
```

second table `product_supplier` with columns

```
psid(pk)
pid(fk from products)
sid(fk from supplier)
```

third table `supplier` with columns

```
id(pk)
firstname
lastname
```

I want to get data from these three tables in one mysql query.

Comment: Can you show us your best attempt at this please

Comment: Actually I don't know how to join three tables, so my try is still limited to two tables

Comment: Well show us what you have and then we can add to it. Put it in the Question, dont post in a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select p.*, s.*
from products p
inner join product_supplier ps on ps.pid = p.id
inner join supplier s on s.id = ps.sid
order by p.id, s.id
```

This will return each product along with all the associated suppliers.

Comment: Yes, It is working Fine. Thank you! But can you please explain a little how this is working?

Comment: @ZaynJutt: these are just simple joins. You might want to google `sql join`, there are *many* online resources where you can learn about this.